# Is there a standard text of the Litany of Loreto accepted for universal use by the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, tradition

The Litany of Loreto recited in Southern India contains a prayer "Glory/pride of the  Order of Carmelites, pray for us" just before the last prayer "Queen of peace, pray for us". That prayer is not found in the English version. May be, the prayer was added to the Litany by the Carmelites who perhaps popularized the Rosary in Southern India. My question therefore is: Is there a standard text of the Litany of Loreto accepted for universal use  by the Catholic Church ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a standard text of the Litany of Loreto accepted for universal use by the Catholic Church?**

The short answer is **yes**.

The universal standard text for the Universal Catholic Church is in Latin and can be found in the ***Rituale Romanum*** [(Page 266)](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf). For standard texts of the above mentioned litany in other vernacular languages, one simply has to look in an approved Vatican translation of the *Litany of Loreto* in the appropriate Roman Ritual of any particular vernacular translation.